# Get daily data from hourly

Tags: sql-server

I have query which returns hourly data. But I want to get daily data from this query, so all the hourly data per day would be averaged to daily data.

```
declare @Days int

set @Days = -1

select      

dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,Timestamp),cast(CAST((Timestamp) as date) as datetime)) as [Time]  
,[value] 



from  [Employee]

where dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,Timestamp),cast(CAST((Timestamp) as date) as datetime)) >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, @Days, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: your question is not clear, please share some sample data from Employee table and sample output data that you are expecting.

Comment: I am getting hourly data like for 1pm,2pm,3pm............ but I want all the data of that day to be averaged to daily data. Daily data means we'll have only one piece of data per day! I don't know what you mean by not clear? I explained it quite well.

Comment: You only want a time like your query shows? Or are there other columns you want averaged? That's what's not clear to me.

Comment: we'll not really. but I added a value column in the post for your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have additional columns you want to average and group by date, you can try something like:

```
DECLARE @Days int = -1;
SELECT 
      CAST(Timestamp AS date) AS date
    , AVG(Value) AS Value
FROM  [Employee]
WHERE Timestamp >= DATEADD(day, @Days, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
GROUP BY CAST(Timestamp AS date)
ORDER BY date;
```

Note the refactored `WHERE` clause that avoids applying a function to the column value. This will allow an index on `Timestamp` to be used efficiently (sargable expression).